# Can I config Kafka Streams internal topics avro schema subject name stategy?

Tags: apache-kafka, avro, apache-kafka-streams, confluent-schema-registry

I develop kafka streams application using stateful operation.
I am using kafka topic about avro type.

Kafka streams internal topics created during my application runs.
schema registy also created internal topics schema.
(class `io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicNameStrategy`)

Can I config internal topics schema subject strategy??
I want to config "`RecordNameStrategy`".

I already config kafka streams below.

```java
config.put(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY, RecordNameStrategy.class.getName());
```

Comment: Try to put `StreamsConfig.topicPrefix(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY)` into the config key

Comment: `config.put(StreamsConfig.topicPrefix(AbstractKafkaAvroSerDeConfig.VALUE_SUBJECT_NAME_STRATEGY));` is not working.

Comment: You still need to put a value of the strategy for that key