# value.subject.name.strategy for multiple event types not applied to internal topics in kafka

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-streams

in kafka, we have a requirement for multiple event types in the same topic. we were able to achieve this using the following configuration:
[value.subject.name.strategy=io.confluent.kafka.serializers.subject.TopicRecordNameStrategy](https://www.confluent.io/blog/put-several-event-types-kafka-topic/)
however, this only partially works as this does not seem to be applied to internal (repartition and change log) topics created during grouping and aggregation. we then tried to configure the [internal topic parameters](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/streams/developer-guide/config-streams.html#internal-topic-parameters) but to no avail.

any suggestions as to how we could resolve this would be appreciated.

Comment: this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57456747/can-i-config-kafka-streams-internal-topics-avro-schema-subject-name-stategy?newreg=04f29cd51b2343499be39962394d84a6) alludes to the same problem but i have no idea if it was resolved.

Comment: As commented there, did you try using the topicPrefix method?

Comment: we did and it works now. we are using spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka-streams and sometimes it confusion as to what we need to configure where. basically, the issues are not the internal topics but the serdes we configure on  #groupByKey(Grouped) and we had created a custom ListSerde for use in Materialized.as (#aggregate) that was reconfiguring the original serdes (I'll get my coat!). many thanks.

Comment: Cool. Feel free to answer your own question below